# Counterexample for equality of preimage of interior and interior of preimage.

Tags: general-topology

I am having difficulties defining a counter example for the following:

Let X and Y be metric spaces and $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous function. Let $S \subseteq Y$. I have shown that $f^{-1}(\breve S) \subseteq Interior(f^{-1}(S))$ already. I know that the equality does not hold but I cannot think of a specific counterexample where the equality doesn't hold.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=cos(x)$, $S=[-1,1]$, then preimage of $S$, and its interior, is the whole real line.

But the interior of $S$ is $(-1,1)$, whose preimage omits $0$ (and other points, of course)

Answer (score 0):

Take the null function $f\colon\mathbb R\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ and take $S=\{0\}$. Then$$f^{-1}\left(\mathring S\right)=f^{-1}(\emptyset)=\emptyset,$$but$$\mathring{\overbrace{f^{-1}(S)}}=\mathring{\mathbb R}=\mathbb R.$$